# zeppelin | 0.8.0 | Disable Helium

Tags: apache-zeppelin

We are running Zeppelin on docker containers in a locked-down enterprise environment. When Zeppelin starts, it tries to connect to AWS, times-out after a while, but successfully starts. The log trace is below -

```
 INFO [2018-09-03 14:26:25,131] ({main} Notebook.java[<init>]:128) - Notebook indexing finished: 0 indexed in 0s
 INFO [2018-09-03 14:26:25,133] ({main} Helium.java[loadConf]:103) - Add helium local registry /opt/zeppelin-0.8.0/helium
 INFO [2018-09-03 14:26:25,134] ({main} Helium.java[loadConf]:100) - Add helium online registry https://s3.amazonaws.com/helium-package/helium.json
 WARN [2018-09-03 14:26:25,138] ({main} Helium.java[loadConf]:111) - /opt/zeppelin-0.8.0/conf/helium.json does not exists



ERROR [2018-09-03 14:28:32,864] ({main} HeliumOnlineRegistry.java[getAll]:80) - Connect to s3.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.81.59] failed: Connection timed out
 INFO [2018-09-03 14:28:33,840] ({main} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:744) - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@ef9296d{/,file:/opt/zeppelin-0.8.0/webapps/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/opt/zeppelin-0.8.0/zeppelin-web-0.8.0.war}
 INFO [2018-09-03 14:28:33,846] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:266) - Started ServerConnector@1b1c538d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9991}
 INFO [2018-09-03 14:28:33,847] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:379) - Started @145203ms
```

We have no use-case for Helium (as of now) and the delay in the zeppelin restart affects us. Is there a way we can disable this dependency on Helium?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to disable the Helium module. The below PR is not available in 0.8. I also want to get rid of the Helium module altogether. Any hints will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

There was [PR3082](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/3082) ([ZEPPELIN-3636] Add timeout for s3 amazon bucket endpoint) that allows not to wait to Amazon.

PR was merged to master, perhaps will be merged to branch-0.8.